# Strange text formatting in Ubuntu console window

Tags: command-line, 18.04, utf-8

Right now I'm running a server on Ubuntu 18.04, and using PM2 to manage my programs. PM2 is supposed to display lots of information in neat tables like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TP4p.jpg). Instead, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gukfX.jpg). What's wrong with the formatting/encoding? I heard it was something to do with UTF-8, and I tried doing everything to do with that but nothing seemed to work. In fact, when in the localization wizard, I was getting the same mess of diacritics (I guess the wizard is supposed to have a box around it).

Comment: what happens if you do `LC_ALL=C pm2 ls`

Comment: @bac0n nothing special happens. Still messed up diacritics instead of a table.

Comment: What langrage you are useing? If you are not using english,the console may cant show that langrage. For example, the console cant show chinese.

Comment: "For example, the console cant show chinese." are you sure about that? :-) `vga=0x317` as a boot option and then install `bterm`... that should allow for Chinese.

Comment: @Emoji right now I'm using US English with UTF-8 enabled